# How to remove an entry from iOS Safari's URL bar?

Tags: ios, safari, bookmarks, browser-history

On my iPad (iOS 8.3, but this also happened with earlier versions), when I start typing in the URL bar, one of the completions is a rather unsavory URL which I visited once.

It appears in the "Bookmarks and History" section.  I've cleared my history in the Safari preferences (and confirmed that my History in Safari has no entries left).  I've gone through all of my bookmarks, and every folder, but it's not there anywhere.

I've looked all over for "how to delete an iOS Safari bookmarks", but they all start with "First, open the Bookmarks, and find the one you want to delete".  It's not there! -- or if it is, it's hidden so I can't find it anywhere.

I've had to reboot my iPad a few times, due to crashes (8.2 was pretty crashy), and that doesn't help, either.

How do I fix this?  Is there some way to reset the URL bar's idea of what's in my bookmarks?

Comment: Do you have other devices using the same iCloud account that might have that URL in *their* history? Safari appears to sync browser history between devices with the appropriate iCloud settings activated.

Comment: To narrow your search, unless you specifically bookmarked it, it is not coming from a bookmark, so don't include that word in your query. There are no "hidden" bookmarks, only browser history. As Dan says, it is likely being synced from another device.

Comment: Dan J: No, I don't use iCloud, and I have never synced my iPad with anything.

Comment: tubedogg: Safari says it's coming from "Bookmarks and History", and it's not in either of these lists.  It's not coming from any sync.  I don't know where it's coming from, but it's *somewhere* hidden.